# Get Path of Gallery Image Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-permissions, android-gallery

I am trying to get the path of Gallery Image. I am getting the path of the image which is stored in internal storage but not of the external storage. I have also enabled the read-write storage and camera access permissions which has been granted. 
Here is my code

```
    void ChoosePhoto()
    {
        try
        {
            var imageIntent = new Intent();
            imageIntent.SetType("image/*");
            imageIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
            StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(imageIntent, "Select photo"), 0);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    } 

protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE)
        {
        // camera operation
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("choose pic from Gallery");
            var uri = data.Data;
            var path = getRealPathFromURI(uri); //path returns null when i select image from external storage;
        }
    }
    private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI)
    {
        string[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Data };
        String result;
        var cursor = ContentResolver.Query(contentURI, proj, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null)
            result = contentURI.Path;
        else
        {
            int idx= cursor.GetColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Data);
            cursor.MoveToFirst();
            result = cursor.GetString(idx);
            cursor.Close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: You mean when you choose a picture from gallery, you want get its path?

Comment: Yes, I want to get the selected image path which I have choose from gallery

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want to get the selected image path which I have choose from gallery

The problem is that  change `Android.Net.Uri` to `path`, here is an solution :

```
private string GetPathToImage(Android.Net.Uri uri)
{
    string doc_id = "";
    using (var c1 = ContentResolver.Query(uri, null, null, null, null))
    {
        c1.MoveToFirst();
        string document_id = c1.GetString(0);
        doc_id = document_id.Substring(document_id.LastIndexOf(":") + 1);
    }

    string path = null;

    // The projection contains the columns we want to return in our query.
    string selection = Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Id + " =? ";
    using (var cursor = ContentResolver.Query(Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri, null, selection, new string[] { doc_id }, null))
    {
        if (cursor == null) return path;
        var columnIndex = cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data);
        cursor.MoveToFirst();
        path = cursor.GetString(columnIndex);
    }
    return path;
}
```

When you choose a picture from gallery :

```
ChoosePhoto();
...
 protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 0)
    {
        var uri = data.Data;
        var path = GetPathToImage(uri);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Image path == " + path );
        //My result is this ==> [0:] Image path == /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20170813_223324.jpg
    }
 }
```

**Most important**, when you use this method, maybe you will come across this problem :

> Java.Lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=21975, uid=10417 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()

When API >= 23, [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html?hl=en-us), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app. You should check  if you have `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, if not, you need to request the permissions.

Comment: York Shen, Thank you very much for the reply. I solved my problem without needing the path of the image. But I am sure I am gonna need this for future reference. I will soon try this code and upvote as it works.

Comment: @Amod, have you try this solution?

Comment: No not yet, I am reaching my deadlines to complete the project. I will soon try it after my deadlines

Comment: Hello @York Shen - MSFT This worked for me. Thank you so much.

Comment: I've tried.
Work as a charm.
Thanks a lot for the objective and nice solution.
As I'm already asking for external storage permission at runtime, this solution is perfect.