# How to get file content chosen with android Intent

Tags: android-intent, get, xamarin.android

I have the following code to browse and choose a file from android file system

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionGetContent);
intent.SetType("*/*");
intent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);
StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select a file"),0);
```

Now I want to get the content of the choosen file. I read that , to do that I have to put some code in

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
}
```

but this code never gets called and from the examples given I don't understand very good what to put in there. The file I want to read is a CSV file abd I want to put its data in an Array.

Comment: Modify your code to : `protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)`.

Comment: thank you. now the debug enters into the method. But how to get the file content. I'm using C# (android). All the answers I found seems to work for Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the file's path when you choose a file from android file system, for example :

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 0)
    {
        var uri = data.Data;
        string path = GetActualPathFromFile(uri);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("File path == " + path);        
    }
}
```

The `GetActualPathFromFile(uri)` method is to get the actual path from `Android.Net.Uri`, for complete code, you could refer to :  [How to get actual path from Uri xamarin android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46975574/how-to-get-actual-path-from-uri-xamarin-android/47008332#47008332)
.

After get the file path, you could get your `CSV` file content by refer to this : [Reading CSV files using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507498/reading-csv-files-using-c-sharp)
.