# How to get file path on any select file on Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin

How can I get the path from any file that I get from local or external storage on android? Here is my code:

```
                Intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionOpenDocument);
                string[] mimetypes =
                 {
                    "application/pdf", "image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/tiff", "application/msword",
                    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
                    "application/vnd.ms-excel", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
                };
                Intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraMimeTypes, mimetypes);
                Intent.SetType("*/*");

                Intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
                Intent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);

                StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(Intent, "Select file"), Constant.PickPDFId);
```

And the OnActivityResults I got:

```
         base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == Constant.PickPDFId && resultCode == Result.Ok && data != null)
        {
            var FilePath= data.Data.Path;

        }
```

The FilePath has a colon in between *'document/3137-3837:Screenshots/Screenshot_2018.png* . How can I get the valid path without the colon?

Answer (score 1):

The Filepath you retrieved here:

```
var FilePath= data.Data.Path;
```

is only a URI, you need to convert it to an actual file path, but because you are returning varius MIME types you need to process the URI differently,

[This updated answer from a post should help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46975574/how-to-get-actual-path-from-uri-xamarin-android)