# How to Get The name of Captured Image with Camera In Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, c#-4.0, xamarin.android

I  want to get the name of the captured image with camera.When user click button camera is open fine but i want to get the name of currently captured Image.

This is the Button Click event when user press the button then camera is opened.

```
fab3.Click += (o, e) =>
            {
              Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
              StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
              CloseFabMenu();

            };
```

And here is i want to read the name of captured image.

```
 protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
      base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      //if ((requestCode == PickImageId) && (resultCode == Result.Ok) && (data != null))
      //{

        switch (requestCode)
        {
          case 0:
            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
              Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data");


            }

            break;
}
```

On Debugging Mode i Get This output.
[image]

Comment: What issue did you occur?Did you not get the uri from `data.Data`? If so, I suggest you create a new file uri `takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,pictureUri);`before `StartActivityForResult`

Comment: what is in pictureUri

Comment: create a uri like this `Uri pictureUri = Uri.FromFile(new File(GetExternalFilesDir(Environment.DirectoryDcim), "test.jpg"));`

Comment: Uri.FromFile not found in Xamarin android

Comment: @zubariz, Do you solve this issue?

Comment: @zubariz, use Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to Get The name of Captured Image with Camera In Xamarin Android

[Convert the `Android.Net.Uri` to actual path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46975574/how-to-get-actual-path-from-uri-xamarin-android/47008332#47008332) and [get the image name from that path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921105/get-file-name-from-a-path-string-in-c-sharp).

Then, you could get the actual path and file name in  `OnActivityResult` :

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 0)
    {
        var uri = data.Data;
        string path = GetActualPathFromFile(uri);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Image path == " + path);
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
    }
}
```

## Update:

You could refer to Aamirkhan's answer [Getting path of captured image in Android using camera intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327213/getting-path-of-captured-image-in-android-using-camera-intent/20327697), it works fine on my side.

Comment: When I'm Capturing The image with Camera The intent Data is Empty.And i just Received  Bitmap .As Above Var uri=data.Date; is Null ,

Comment: @zubairz, you need an extra `getImageUri` method, then, get the image `uri` from your bitmap via this `getImageUri` metho. please check my updated answer.

Comment: Ok Sir Let Check it

Comment: Sir i have one an other problem not related to this Question ..if you Allow me i can ask?

Comment: @zubairz, feel free to say

Comment: Can i use xam.plugin.Madia with Xamarin android

Comment: @zubairz, I would recommend you use the `xam.plugin.Madia` [android part source code](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/tree/master/src/Media.Plugin/Android) directly.