# Uri Path is not compatible with Java.IO.File

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, path

I use a button to find a file in the phone:

```
    private void button_save_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Intent chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ActionGetContent);
        chooseFile.SetType("*/*");
        chooseFile = Intent.CreateChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a file");
        StartActivityForResult(chooseFile, 1000);
    }
```

And then I try to use the given path to open the selected file:

```
    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode is 1000 && resultCode is Result.Ok)
        {
            var uri = data.Data;
            string path = uri.Path;
            Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(path);

        }
    }
```

but the format of  `uri.Path` is incompatible with `Java.IO.File` and the file is not opened. How can I get a compatible full path to a file?

Comment: Please tell the value of uri.Path and uri.String. And make clear why it is not compatible according to you.

Comment: `How can I get a compatible full path to a file?` You will not do such nasty things as you should use that uri to handle the file. Even if you were able to convert the uri to a path then you would not have access under Android 10. Well mostly not.

Comment: @blackapps uri.Path is "/document/primary:Telegram/Telegram Images/00.jpg" and  uri.String is undefined

Comment: Can be undefined as i dont know xamarin. I wanted to know the full uri. The full content scheme. There will be another member that will tell you. And you us.

Comment: "uri = {content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ATelegram%2FTelegram%20Images%2F00.jpg}"

Comment: @blackapps to be comptible the path must be "/sdcard/Telegram/Telegram Images/00.jpg" instead.

Comment: Well not too difficult to convert that scheme to your wanted path. But why would you need a path? You can do all with that uri.

Comment: @blackapps There are a lot of File classes in C#. Are they compatible with Uri? How do you use Uri?

Comment: Well the question is if you can open a stream for that content scheme in C#. I dont know .. C#.

Comment: If you want to get the full path url from a content url, you can have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47008332/10539446).