# How to get all Photo file for xamarin.forms in IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I want to implement based on Xamarin.Forms cross platform, Android and iOS respectively obtain the function of photo albums or pictures under the platform

Use scenarios such as I have a page with all the pictures for users to choose from, for example, We-chat chooses multiple pictures.

The page control can be completed. Now I don't know how to get all the pictures and the path of the pictures.
Thanks !

Comment: Xamarin Essentials includes a Media Picker control - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?tabs=ios

Comment: Thank you. I used this component before. When I Used it, this control directly opens the default page for selecting the picture list. This page can be multi selected, but there is no order of clicking. I need an implementation similar to the current picture order in the upper right corner.
Therefore, it is considered to give up the use of this component. Instead, get all the pictures and display them on the customized list page.

Comment: I tried to get pictures under Android ——https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46975574/how-to-get-actual-path-from-uri-xamarin-android.
Because I haven't contacted IOS, I have some doubts about the acquisition of pictures under IOS

Comment: Essentials is open source, so you are free to modify the Media Picker to better suit your needs

Answer (score 0):

For iOS you can use **PhotoKit in Xamarin.iOS** which allows you to customize a user interface and modify its content.

For information on its use, please refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/photokit

Comment: Has the problem been resolved?